# Help with permissions

Tags: permissions, echo, touch

I am trying to set up permissions, but I don't know what exactly, as a user.

Could anyone tell me which permission will allow me to execute the touch and echo commands in a directory?

Comment: Can you go to the directory and type `ls -la` and also provide what username you are logged in as?

Comment: i am user in group user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone should be able to execute the `echo` command.  If you can't there's something seriously wrong with your Linux install.  To run `touch` you need to have write access to the destination directory.

Comment: Thank you David, and is there a difference in permissions between binary executable in a directory ?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question.  Can you try asking again?

Comment: I mean which permission is necessary to run a binary executable in a directory with 755 permissions ? I am just beginer in Linux :)

Comment: You need to have the read permission on the directory itself and the read and execute permissions on the binary.